# Алгоритм парсинга различных таблиц

Tags: android, парсер

Ситуация такова. Есть список игроков. По клику из списка, открывается активити с подробной информацией об игроке и статистической таблицей. Игроков больше 50. У каждого информация одного и того же формата(это парсится без проблем) и таблицы, которые имеют разное количество строк и столбцов, у каждого игрока она может отличаться от других, определённой закономерности нет.Вопрос:по какому единому алгоритму парсить таблицы, чтобы потом всё в нужном для меня формате вставить в TableView своего приложения. Возможно использовать один общий алгоритм для разнокалиберных таблиц или так не делают? Таблицы взяты со страниц одного сайта, созданы они при помощи обычного html.
Примеры таблиц:

таблица 1:[image: таблица 1]

таблица 2:[image: таблица 2]

таблица 3:[image: таблица 3]

таблица 4:[image: таблица 4]

Comment: добавьте пример с полями игроков.

Comment: Пилите гири, Шура :) Если "определённой закономерности нет", то о каком "едином алгоритме" может быть речь?

Comment: @Andriy Martsinkevych , дополнил вопрос скринами таблиц.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja предлагаете запилить 50 индивидуальных активити со своими таблицами и парсить для каждой? это как же вырастет код и объём. Что, неужели гуру пользуются такими методами?

Comment: сколько всего возможно разных полуй в игроков?

Comment: Гуру для таких кейсов используют метаданные (описание структуры данных)

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych 6 столбцов и 6 строк

Comment: А о каких таблицах вообще речь? База данных, Excell таблицы или ещё что-то?

Comment: @eugeneek , моё упущение, не упомянул, что таблицы взяты со страниц одного сайта, созданы они при помощи обычного html.

Answer (score 0):

Варианта два:

1. Подгонять входные данные под единый формат и тогда парсить их единым алгоритмом.
2. Писать ветвистый алгоритм парсинга, по сути несколько алгоритмов под каждый тип данных.

Comment: Что значит подгонять входные данные под единый формат?

Comment: У вас тут наскидку мало общего между данными. Если вариантов таблиц немного, проще в лоб все их описать.

Comment: Таблиц 54. Пока,дальше возможно будет больше

Comment: Тогда надо придумать структуру метаданных, как описать эти структуры данных.

Comment: это моё первое приложение и я не могу понять как мне связать структуры данных и таблицы на сайте. загонять всё в какой-нибудь мап, а оттуда потом раскидывать по моему `TableView` ?