# Как вставить в WebView кусок со страницы сайта?

Tags: android, webview

Можно ли вставить в WebView кусок со страницы сайта? Конкретно нужна только таблица "Персональная статистика". Если возможно, то как? Или может быть есть другие способы это сделать? Сама страница : http://laf.amfoot.ru/?r=person/view&person=1604

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно распарсить эту страницу. Попробуйте эту библиотеку: [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download)

Посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772828/how-to-parse-html-table-using-jsoup) тоже

Comment: С этого, впринципе, я и начал. Возникли сложности, поэтому подумал о ещё возможныx вариантах

Comment: Видел. В этом в примере рассматривается одна таблица. Спарсить одну не составляет проблем. У меня ситуация посложнее, а именно : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/695227/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86

Comment: Я так понял что сайт не ваш. Вообще парсить такое количество таблиц, не самое правильное решение

Comment: Да, сайт не мой. А как тогда быть?